# Does memory get freed when reassigning std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Given the following:

```cpp
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> foo;
    foo = std::make_unique<char[]>(100);
    foo = std::make_unique<char[]>(200);
}
```

Does the memory allocated in the first call to make_unique get freed when reassigning foo with the second call?

Comment: "Can I redefine foo at will without a memory leak" - You can re-_assign_ `foo`.

Comment: Side note: in the general case, prefer `std::vector` to a smart pointer to an array. Profiling or other circumstances will tell you when you need to switch away from `std::vector`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no leak in this code.  [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) for `std::unique_ptr` will call the `Deleter` (in this example, `delete[]`) for the existing memory when transferring ownership from another `unique_ptr` that is being assigned to it.

Per cppreference:

[`std::unique_ptr<T,Deleter>::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D)

> Transfers ownership from `r` to `*this` as if by calling `reset(r.release())` followed by an assignment of `get_deleter()` from `std::forward<E>(r.get_deleter())`.

[`std::unique_ptr<T,Deleter>::reset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset)

> Given `current_ptr`, the pointer that was managed by `*this`, performs the following actions, in this order:
>
> - Saves a copy of the current pointer `old_ptr = current_ptr`
> - Overwrites the current pointer with the argument `current_ptr = ptr`
> - **If the old pointer was non-empty, deletes the previously managed object
>
>   `if(old_ptr) get_deleter()(old_ptr)`**

Answer (score 2):

You only define `foo` once.
Specifically, in the first line in the scope:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> foo;
```

As it is default-initialized, the default-ctor is called, which initializes with `nullptr`.

The other two lines assign a new value to `foo`, no re-definition which would be *an error*.

And yes, if you assign a new value to `foo`, the assignment-operator will free the previously owned memory, guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `unique_ptr` has an array specialization which will call the array-wide destructor when the unique_ptr goes out of scope:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

As you can see in the last example, where it creates an array of Ds, then calls the destructor for all the Ds that were created.